# Eclipse from Unity3D

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I have built a game using Unity 3D and export it to an APK file to test it on a device, but when installing and try to run it  on the device it gives me this message : 
Unfortunately Mygame has stopped.
So I tried to export the project to Eclipse to get the log for the error and the log give me this :

```
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.grafid.soccer/com.grafid.soccer.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.grafid.soccer.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.grafid.soccer-2.apk
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.grafid.soccer.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.grafid.soccer-2.apk
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
01-05 10:57:15.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2063):     ... 11 more
01-05 10:57:20.774: I/Process(2063): Sending signal. PID: 2063 SIG: 9
```

Information :
I'm usign the latest Unity 3D version
Eclipse Juno
Targeted Android version 2.3.1 "ginger" and  above (on Unity3D)

manifest xml : 
http://pastebin.com/A2JL0cMT

Thnak you for your Help ^^

Comment: does com.grafid.soccer.MainActivity exist?

Comment: I searched for it and it doesn't exist actually. and Im not sure how to add it and what's should in it.